# How do I create a parallelogram with CSS, but without transforms

Tags: css

I've got this, so far, I want to put together the triangles and the rectangle to get a parallelogram. Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/pu17bbfo/

I can't use transforms because this is targeting wkhtmltopdf and it doesn't support them.

Code:

```
<div style="display: block; ">
<div style="width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 0 72px 40px;
border-color: transparent transparent #f17522 transparent; display: inline-block;">
</div>
<div style="height: 72px; background-color: #f17522; display: inline-block;">
<p style="color: #fff">Talking Points Name</p>
</div>
<div style="width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 72px 40px 0 0;
border-color: #f17522 transparent transparent transparent; display: inline-block;">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `inline-block` elements will have `vertical-align: baseline`. You can use `top` or `bottom` there and they will vertically align. Then either remove the white space between the elements to remove the gap, or put an HTML comment there that will remove the white space displayed on the page.

```css
.headline {
  height: 72px;
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #f17522;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}

div {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: block; ">
  <div style="width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 0 72px 40px;
border-color: transparent transparent #f17522 transparent; display: inline-block;">
  </div><!--
--><div style="height: 72px; background-color: #f17522; display: inline-block;">
    <p style="color: #fff">Talking Points Name</p>
  </div><!--
--><div style="width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 72px 40px 0 0;
border-color: #f17522 transparent transparent transparent; display: inline-block;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `absolute` position in the div's.